# How could I convert this formatted string into a key, value dictionary form?

Tags: python, string, dictionary

I am not pretty sure how to convert a formatted string into a dictionary, what I was thinking was to separate my string into two lists and then join them into a dictionary  but I am convinced that there must be a way to convert it from string to dictionary directly.

This is what I get so far:

string:

```
'Me_of_temp_max: 13.91 Me_of_temp_min: 11.33 Me_of_p_max: 14.25 Me_of_p_min: 14.53'
```

What I am looking fro is this:

```
{'Me_of_temp_max': 13.91, 'Me_of_temp_min': 11.33, 'Me_of_p_max': 14.25, 'Me_of_p_min': 14.53}
```

But What I did to reach this was:

```
items = {}


result = ['Me_of_temp_max', 'Me_of_temp_min', 'Me_of_p_ma', 'Me_of_p_min']
result1 = [13.91, 11.33, 14.25, 14.53]
for i in range(len(result)):
        items[result[i]] = result1[i]
return items
```

Comment: Where do the numeric values in your dictionary come from? How does 13.91 become 18.38?

Comment: from a formatted operation? is that important?

Comment: Well, yes, because I don't know know by what logic you go from the string `'13.91'` to the int `18.38`, so I can't offer you a solution.

Comment: Given that numbers pop up from nowhere - yes it's important to describe the reasoning behind them...

Comment: Oh i see... sorry it was a typing error. They must be exactly the same values. Sorry

Comment: Please check my answer, itll be easy to follow compared to other options I believe. If you have any questions let me know.

Comment: and remove the whitespace before the p of  'Me_of_ p_min: 14.53' unless thats a valid entry which would invalidate most solutions based on string split at ' '

Comment: Please mark my answer as correct if it worked for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd want to split on `(space)` and then iterate over those values.

```
s = 'Me_of_temp_max: 13.91 Me_of_temp_min: 11.33 Me_of_p_max: 14.25 Me_of_p_min: 14.53'

s_key_vals = s.replace(':', '').split(' ')

res = {}
for idx, key in enumerate(s_key_vals):
    if idx % 2 == 0: # will be an even number, every time ``idx`` is even, it means key is a value like: ``Me_of_temp_min`` or ``Me_of_p_min`` etc
        res[key] = float(s_key_vals[idx+1])  # Convert the number to a float instead of being left with a string.
```

Returns: `{'Me_of_temp_min': 11.33, 'Me_of_p_min': 14.53, 'Me_of_temp_max': 13.91, 'Me_of_p_max': 14.25}`

Answer (score 2):

A simple two liner using `split` and `replace` to process the string, and `zip` to build the `dictionary` :

```
>>> t = s.replace(':','').split()
>>> dict( zip(t[::2], list(map(float,t[1::2]))) )
```

#driver values :

```
IN : s = 'Me_of_temp_max: 13.91 Me_of_temp_min: 11.33 Me_of_p_max: 14.25 Me_of_p_min: 14.53'
OUT : {'Me_of_temp_max': 13.91, 'Me_of_temp_min': 11.33, 'Me_of_p_max': 14.25, 'Me_of_p_min': 14.53}
```

---

Further explanation :

1. the `replace` function is used to remove all `':'` in the strings as they are not required.
2. the `split` function with space as delimiter gives us the list with key and values.
3. the `zip` function creates the `key-value` pair for the `dict`

   - and since the `keys` are in the *even positions*, we get required list by using `extended slicing` as `[::2]`.
   - and since the `values` are in the *odd positions*, we get required list by using `extended slicing` as `[1::2]`. And since the values should be *float* we use `map` to get list containing float values.
4. finally `type-cast` it to `dict`  .

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
input = "Me_of_temp_max: 13.91 Me_of_temp_min: 11.33 Me_of_p_max: 14.25 Me_of_p_min: 14.53"

spl = input.split("Me") 
spl_noempty = [("Me"+x).strip().split(':') for x in spl if x != ''] 

dic = dict(spl_noempty)
print(dic)
```

I split at `Me`, remove whitespaces. I prepend `Me` again and split each part at `:` to form a list of tuples, then `dict` them.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to do it with a regular expression, which means you may need to change it to suit the exact format of your data.

```
import re

s = 'Me_of_temp_max: 13.91 Me_of_temp_min: 11.33 Me_of_p_max: 14.25 Me_of_p_min: 14.53'
regex = re.compile('(\w+):\s(\d+\.\d+)')
{k: float(v) for k, v in regex.findall(s)}
```

Output :

```
{'Me_of_p_max': 14.25,
 'Me_of_p_min': 14.53,
 'Me_of_temp_max': 13.91,
 'Me_of_temp_min': 11.33}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use `string.split(' ')' and latter take care of ':'. In this way you have a list where even and odd places contain the key and the number (as a string).